# I need help identifying a component on my ps vita motherboard

Tags: pcb, resistors, usb, surface-mount

I need help identifying a component on my PS Vita 2000 motherboard. It seems to be a resistor of some sort that is connected to the ID pin out for the micro USB and it is a millimeter in length.
I’m trying to figure out what it is as I seem to have knocked that component off of my second board. I want to know what it is so that I can replace it to put another one onto my other board.

edit: so it is definitely a resistor that is connected to the ID pin and grounded to the ground pin on the board.
When I measured it on the board it measured 121K ohms, however, when I took it off, I could not get a reading and then proceeded to lose the component.
I have looked more thoroughly into this and for similar devices the rating on these resistors varies anywhere from 5K ohms to 126K ohms.

The board when measured without the resistor reads 116K ohms (with my other board measuring 100k ohms), if anyone has any further ideas on this it would be appreciated, or if you happen to have one of these PS Vita motherboards and would be able to measure the resistor on the ID pinout -desoldered from the board-, if you could give me the measurement of it I would find that very helpful.

Thanks everybody for your help so far.

[image: photo of board with component highlighted]

Comment: Probably a resistor. You'll have to measure it to see what value, it looks unmarked.

Comment: Okay so it measures 121k ohms but when i looked for a part that matches the specs there is the option for thin film or thick film. Is there a way to tell what type of film is on the resistor on the board? Or will it be fine Replacing it with either or.

Comment: I think the film type is not important here. Did you desolder it during measurement? I would not expect 121 kohm there, but who knows...

Comment: No I didn’t desolder it during measurement.(however there is no power or battery connected to the board)

Comment: I have desoldered the resistor. However, I couldn’t get a measurement on it. I measured both boards without the resistor and one measured 100 K ohms, and one measured 119 K ohms. I’m assuming this means that the resistor is either 21K ohms or 3K ohms, respectively.

Comment: The 120k resistor on ID pin means that the device uses "accessory mode", i.e. it has an upstream USB port as a device, but can provide VBUS as a host.

Comment: @ale-chenski ah thanks I will try a 121k resistor and see if it works